# What is the term for practitioners of pseudoscience?

Tags: single-word-requests

Certain disciplines, generally called [pseudosciences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience), falsely claim that they make **actionable** truthful statements about observable objective reality.

Examples are [astrology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology), [homeopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathy), [psychiatry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-psychiatry#Psychiatry_as_a_pseudo-science).

How would you call a *sincere* practitioner (not a researcher/populariser) of such a discipline?

Not "charlatan" - the perpetrator is as deluded as the victim.

Not "pseudo-scientist" - just like a practicing surgeon would not be called a "scientist": this term seems to imply "original contribution" to the discipline as opposed to simply "plying the trade".

Comment: Er...why *not* pseudoscientist? That's how Wikipedia [categorizes such people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pseudoscientists), and the word is also found in dictionaries.

Comment: Perhaps they're all *quacks*.

Comment: What do you mean by "actionable truthful statements"? *Actionable* generally has something to do with ending up in court, which seems at odds with *truthful*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: truthful statements can undoubtedly land you in court, for a variety of reasons (libel/slander is the commonest). But OP clearly means 'useful to act on' or something similar.

Comment: A *crank*; but this is not restricted to those hold only scientifically eccentric opinions.

Comment: Revolutionary? :D

Comment: How about ***so-called** scientists?*. Or just "scientists" in quotes, just like that? Quote marks are a common device for indicating that the writer is using a word "loosely", and you can convey the same effect in speech by added a slight pause before and after the "questionable" word, and giving it exaggerated emphasis.

Comment: There's a pretty big disconnect between provably fiction-based disciplines like astrology and soft sciences like psychiatry.

Comment: @Marcus_33: I wish I could believe that. The only real difference that I've seen after 50 years of dealing with shrinks is that they're required to have an MD to operate their Ouija boards. The rat-psych & clinical-psych [people who created modern advertising & marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Cheskin), OTOH, are rocket scientists in comparison.

Comment: @Marcus_33: take a look at the link I supply; specifically the "pseudopatient experiment".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ODO's entry for [pseudoscience](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pseudoscience) has a section which reads:

> **Derivatives**
>
> **pseudoscientific**
>   **Pronunciation:** /-ˈtɪfɪk/ *adjective*
>
> **pseudoscientist**
>   *noun*

As noted in the comments to your question, *pseudoscientist* is perfectly acceptable and recognised.

Comment: And despite OPs opinion, a surgeon can be and is called 'a practitioner of medical science'.

Comment: A "practitioner of a science" is not the same as "scientist". The latter implies "original research", the former implies "use the results in professional practice".

Comment: @sds: but there is no original research in pseudoscience, since no factual results can be obtained.  Practitioners of pseudosciences are pseudoscientists, with no relation to scientists. Metaphysicians practise metaphysics, with no relation to physicians (or indeed physicists).

Comment: @TimLymington: if there were no original research, the field would not have existed: someone had to come up with their crap in the first place. However, since it appears that a plurality of commenters like the term, let it be.

Answer (score 1):

As disciplines such as astrology, homeopathy, etc deal with the realms not provable by physics, then I think it is fair to call them metaphysical occupations and their practitioners, metaphysicians.

Comment: Which would be perfectly viable considering there are metaphysical shops specifically for these things. +1

Comment: claims made by astrologists et al are falsifiable and have been repeatedly falsified on each attempt.

Comment: Not to be disrespectful here, but you are taking exception with my choice of wording rather than responding to my actual answer. That seems just a bit disingenuous on your part. It makes me wonder if you are truly looking for an answer to your question or have you laid the trap to pick we well-meaing strangers to epistemological pieces?

Comment: *Metaphysics* is a specific philosophical subject, though perhaps no longer classed as a science.  Both metaphysicians and pseudocientists would probably object to confusing the two.

Comment: @ZacImboden: first, "physicians" practice medicine, not physics, you probably meant "metaphysicists"; second, I agree with TimLymington.

Comment: @sds: I might be wrong, but I suspect this answer is meant to be a pun.